Split String in Pandas Series
Can I use the split() function to transfer this series:
s = pd.Series(['adh', 'bei', np.nan, 'cfj'])

To either one of those outputs:
s = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    'B': ['d', 'e', 'f'],
    'C': ['h', 'i', 'j']
})

or:
s = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['a', 'b', np.nan, 'c'],
    'B': ['d', 'e', np.nan, 'f'],
    'C': ['h', 'i', np.nan, 'j']
})


Stop putting a solution in the question. That's what answers are for.

You can str.split with a regex matching a character before and after the split point:
s.str.split('(?<=.)(?=.)', expand=True)

Output:
     0    1    2
0    a    d    h
1    b    e    i
2  NaN  NaN  NaN
3    c    f    j

To avoid the NaNs, add a dropna:
s.dropna().str.split('(?<=.)(?=.)', expand=True)

Output:
   0  1  2
0  a  d  h
1  b  e  i
3  c  f  j

Regex
regex demo
(?<=.)  # match a character before
        # match empty string
(?=.)   # match a character after

Alternatively, you could also convert each string to list and pass to the DataFrame constructor:
out = pd.DataFrame(map(list, s.dropna()))


Any issue with my answer?

Thank you :-)
If it is OK, would you mind explain your regexp for me please?

I added a description of the regex
